# How to make dropdown from list.tupples and submit the value?

Tags: python, web2py

```
<form name="cnf" action="{{=URL('default','dashboard')}}" method="post" onsubmit="return showcnf()" >
    <select name="c_area">
        <option value="">Select Company</option>
        <option value="Headmasters Salon Pvt. Ltd.">Headmasters Salon Pvt. Ltd.</option>
    </select>
    <select name="c_loc">
        <option value="">Select Location</option>
        <option value= 1>Chandigarh</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

in place of select I want to use `tuple`/`list`. Is there any option to do that?
I have tried something:

```
def dropdowan():
    list = []
    for row_l in db( (db.tracker.client_manager==auth.user.email)  ).select():
        list.append(row_l.company)

    abc=set(list)
    return dict(form=abc)
```

I am geting the value from database. Now I want to put in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your table like this:

```
db.define_table('your_table_name',
    Field('select_1', requires=IS_IN_SET(['option_1', 'option2', 'option3'])),
    Field('select_2', requires=IS_IN_SET(['option_1', 'option2', 'option3']))
    Field('another_field', 'text'))
```

and then you can use the `web2py` built-in `SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget` to do the magic for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have done some think . Hope it will be ok

```
 def dropdowan():
        list = []
        clist=[]
        for row_l in db( (db.tbl.field==auth.user.email)  ).select():
            list.append(row_l.f1)
            clist.append(row_l.f2)

        abc=set(list)
        city=set(clist)
        form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('select_company', requires =  IS_IN_SET(abc)),Field('select_city', requires =  IS_IN_SET(city)))
        if form.accepts(request,session):
            session.company = form.vars.select_company
            session.loc = form.vars.select_city

            #redirect=dashboard()
            redirect(URL('dasboard'))

        return dict(form1=form)
```

Comment: This would be a far better answer if you were to tell the Op how this now works - what it now means, and specifically what the asker has missed in their code.